# Needed current first day of week to next two week in jQuery via date-picker

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am new in `jQuery` and `cakePhp 2` and working in a scenario where I need to active date-picker, from current first day of week to next two weeks.

And other days must be disabled. How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var minDate=new Date();
 var maxDate=new Date();
               $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker_recurring_start", function () {
                   $(this).datepicker({
                    minDate:"now",
                     maxDate: "+2w",
                   showButtonPanel:true,
                       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                   });
               });
           });
```

Here, is my code. But i need to start from current week. if one day pass then it will be disable but no days will be added until this two week is finished

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Please add some code..and what you have tried so far..

Comment: I already edit and add my code. have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your input field

```
<input id="thedate" class="datepicker_recurring_start" type="text" />
```

I created a function which gives start date of Current week

```
function getWeeksFirstDate(){
    var startDate = new Date(); // Select date
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay());
      return startDate;
}
```

and used above method to write beforeShow which gets fired when ever datepicker is opened

```
$('.datepicker_recurring_start').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel:true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShow: function() {
         // First of week
        var startDate = getWeeksFirstDate();
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate); // setting min Date
        var endDate = getWeeksFirstDate();
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 13); // adding 2 week to it 
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDate);  // setting max date 
     }
});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3419/)

Edit

To disable prev days of current week

```
$(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());
```

[Updated Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3419/)

Comment: it works thaxs. but i want to make scenario  where= "previous days will be disable (including within week days)".

Comment: In that case you can play around with minDate value, let it be today